# Context capturing in a Structured PDF?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, feature-extraction, ocr

I'm trying to extract resume (PDF) data. resumes always tend to follow a structure. so if you see some numbers in a cv; according to the context, we could tell whether its a telephone number, a birthday, or a date period. if I can classify/identify one entity then that would increase my ability to classify an entity near to it.

I'm still a newbie and appreciate if anyone could give me any thoughts on approaching this problem. what kind of machine learning models should i focus on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if this is really a machine learning problem.  If you can get to text out of the PDF then you should be able to do a lot with a rules-based text analysis algorithm.

Comment: Two specific examples of software with OCR and data extraction capability are ABBYY FineReader and Instabase. If you're looking to scan and extract data from resumes, probably no need at all to craft some bespoke machine learning.